# Applying a given formula to induction step.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I am struggling with the formal proof using induction specifically how would one use the given formula in the induction step?

Consider the sequence generated by taking $x_1 = 2$ and
$x_{n+1} =\sqrt {2x_n − 1}$

Use induction to show that $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically non-increasing.
[Hint: Use the the following formula in the induction step:
$\sqrt{u} − \sqrt{v} = \frac{u − v}{\sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v}}$

so far I can state P(n) and verify that $\{x_1\}$ > $\{x_2\}$ for a specific n. I have shown it is bounded and converges to 1. I am not sure how to use the given formula in the induction step. A walk through of this or a similar example to aid my understanding would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you meant to write:
$$x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2x_n-1}$$

The square root looks a bit weird in your post but I'm guessing that this is what you wanted. So, we have that:
$$x_{n+1}-x_n = \sqrt{2x_n-1} -x_n = \frac{2x_n-1-x_n^2}{\sqrt{2x_n-1}+x_n} = \frac{-(x_n^2-2x_n+1)}{\sqrt{2x_n-1}+x_n} = \frac{-(x_n-1)^2}{\sqrt{2x_n-1}+x_n} \leq 0$$

and this implies that it is a non-increasing sequence. I am actually using your formula in the second equality above.

Answer (score 0):

To use the induction hypothesis that $x_n \le x_{n-1}$,

$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}-x_n &= \sqrt{2x_n -1} - \sqrt{2x_{n-1}-1}\\
&= \frac{2x_n-1-2x_{n-1}+1}{\sqrt{2x_n -1} + \sqrt{2x_{n-1}-1}}\\
&= \frac{2(x_n-x_{n-1})}{\sqrt{2x_n -1} + \sqrt{2x_{n-1}-1}}\\
&\le 0\\
x_{n+1} &\le x_n
\end{align*}$$

With the base case (that is to be proven), the sequence of $x$ is non-increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

$x_1 > x_2.$

Assume that $x_{n-1} > x_n$.  Per the hint given, consider

$$x_n - x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2x_{n-1} - 1} - \sqrt{2x_n - 1} = \frac{2x_{n-1} - 2x_n}{\text{a positive value}}. \tag1 $$

From the induction hypothesis, the numerator on the RHS of (1) above is positive.

Therefore, the entire fraction is positive.

Therefore, $x_n - x_{n+1}$ is positive.

So, if $~x_{n-1} - x_n~$ is positive, then so is $~x_n - x_{n+1}.$